# C# WinForms Chart Control: get Size,Region,Position of Bar

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

is there a way to get the rectangles of the stackcolumn chart bar?

this code snippet is how it can be works but it's very ugly:

```
            var points = new List<Point>();
            for (int x = 0; x < chart.Size.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < chart.Size.Height; y++)
                {
                    var hp = chart.HitTest(x, y, false, ChartElementType.DataPoint);
                    var result = hp.Where(h => h.Series?.Name == "Cats");
                    if (result.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        points.Add(new Point(x, y));
                    }
                }
            }
            var bottomright = points.First();
            var topleft = points.Last();
```

I will try to describe my purpose:
I would like to create a chart from various testresults and make this available as a HTML file. This generated Chart is inserted as an image file in the HTML document. Now, I would like to link each part of a Bar area from the Chart to an external document. Since the graphics is static, I have only the possibility to use the "MAP Area" element to make any area as a link from HTML. The "map" element requires a "rectangle", or these coordinates. That's the reason why I need the coordinator of each part of a Bar.
I have to mention that I am not really familiar with the Chart control yet.

[image]

The graphics is generated testweise.

**[SOLVED]**
i got the solution:

```
            var stackedColumns = new List<Tuple<string,string,Rectangle>>();
            for (int p = 0; p < chart.Series.Select(sm => sm.Points.Count).Max(); p++)
            {                               
                var totalPoints = 0;
                foreach (var series in chart.Series)
                {
                    var width = int.Parse(series.GetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth"));
                    var x = (int)area.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(p + 1) - (width / 2);
                    int y = (int)area.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(totalPoints);
                    totalPoints += series.Points.Count > p ? (int)series.Points[p].YValues[0] : 0;
                    int y_total = (int)area.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(totalPoints);
                    var rect = new Rectangle(x, y_total, width, Math.Abs(y - y_total));
                    stackedColumns.Add(new Tuple<string, string, Rectangle>(series.Name, series.Points.ElementAtOrDefault(p)?.AxisLabel, rect));                        
                }
            }
```

this workaround works for stackedcolumn and points starts at x-axis=0. 
just the PixelPointWidth property has to be set manualy to get the right width. i have not yet found a way to get the default bar width..

Comment: This is a simple question but there is no simple answer, I'm afraid. I have tested your trick and also optimized it, but it is always __off by 1-2 pixels__ for the width of the datapoints of the __last series__. - Can you tell us what you need to rectangles for? Maybe my optimized solution would do..

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely tricky and I really wish I knew how to get the bounds from some chart functionionality!

You code snippet is actulally a good start for a workaround. I agree though that it has issues:

- It is ugly
- It doesn't always work
- It has terrible performance

Let's tackle these issues one by one:

- Yes it is ugly, but then that's the way of workarounds. My solution is even uglier ;-)
- There are two things I found don't work:

  - You can't call a `HitTest` during a `Pre/PostPaint` event or terrible things will happen, like some `Series` go missing, SO exceptions or other crashes..
  - The result for the **widths** of the **last** `Series` are **off** by 1-2 pixels.
- The performance of testing each pixel in the chart will be terrible even for small charts, but gets worse and worse when you enlarge the chart. This is relatively easy to prevent, though..:

What we are searching are bounding rectangles for each `DataPoint` of each `Series`.

A rectangle is defined by left and right or width plus top and bottom or height.

We can get precise values for **top** and **bottom** by using the axis function `ValueToPixelPosition` feeding in the y-value and `0` for each point. This is simple and cheap.

With that out of the way we still need to find the **left** and **right** edges of the points. To do so all we need to do it test along the zero-line. (All points will either start or end there!)

This greatly reduces the number of tests.

I have decided to do the testing for each series separately, restaring at `0` each time. For even better performance one could do it all in one go.

Here is a function that returns a `List<Rectangle>` for a given `Series`:

```
List<Rectangle> GetColumnSeriesRectangles(Series s, Chart chart, ChartArea ca)
{
    ca.RecalculateAxesScale();

    List<Rectangle> rex = new List<Rectangle>();
    int loff = s == chart.Series.Last() ? 2 : 0; ;
    int y0 = (int)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(0);
    int left = -1;
    int right = -1;
    foreach (var dp in s.Points)
    {
        left = -1;
        int delta = 0;
        int off = dp.YValues[0] > 0 ? delta : -delta;
        for (int x = 0; x < chart.Width; x++)
        {
            var hitt = chart.HitTest(x, y0 +off );

            if (hitt.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint &&
                ((DataPoint)hitt.Object) == dp)
            {
                if (left < 0) left = x;
                right = x;
            }
            else if (left > 0 && right > left) break;
        }
        int y =  (int)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[0]);
        rex.Add(new Rectangle(left, Math.Min(y0, y), 
                              right - left + 1 - loff, Math.Abs(y - y0)));
        left = -1;
    }
    return rex;
}
```

A few notes:

- I start by doing a `RecalculateAxesScale` because we can't Hittest before the current layout has been calculated.
- I use a helper variable `loff` to hold the offset for the width in the last `Series`.
- I start searching at the last x coordinate as the points should all lie in sequence. If they don't because you have used funny x-values or inserted points you may need to start at `0` instead..
- I use `y0` as the baseline of the zero values for both the hittesting y and also the points' base.
- I use a little Math to get the bounds right for both positive and negative y-values.

Here is a structure to hold those rectangles for all `Series` and code to collect them:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Rectangle>> ChartColumnRectangles = null;

Dictionary<string, List<Rectangle>> GetChartColumnRectangles(Chart chart, ChartArea ca)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<Rectangle>> allrex = new Dictionary<string, List<Rectangle>>();
    foreach (var s in chart.Series)
    {
        allrex.Add(s.Name, GetColumnSeriesRectangles(s, chart, ca));
    }
    return allrex;
}
```

We need to re-calculate the rectangles whenever we add points or resize the chart; also whenever the axis view changes. The common code for `AxisViewChanged`, `ClientSizeChanged`, `Resize` and any spot you add or remove points could look like this:

```
Chart chart= sender as Chart;
GetChartColumnRectangles(chart, chart.ChartAreas[0]);
```

Let's test the result with a Paint event:

```
private void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    chart1.ApplyPaletteColors();
    foreach (var kv in ChartColumnRectangles)
    {
        {
            foreach (var r in kv.Value)
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r);
        }
    }
}
```

Here it is in action:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've been down this path and the BIG issue for me is that the custom property of 'PixelPointWidth' is just that - it is custom.  You cannot retrieve it unless you've set it.  I needed the width of the item - had to scwag/calculate it myself.  Keep in mind that many charts can be panned/zoomed, so once you go down this path, then you need to recalculate it and set it for the chart prepaint events.

Here is a crude little function I made (is more verbose than needed - for educational purposes and has no error handling :)):

```
        private int CalculateChartPixelPointWidth(Chart chart, ChartArea chartArea, Series series)
    {
        // Get right side - takes some goofy stuff - as the pixel location isn't available
        var areaRightX = Math.Round(GetChartAreaRightPositionX(chart, chartArea));
        var xValue = series.Points[0].XValue;
        var xPixelValue = chartArea.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(xValue);

        var seriesLeftX = chart.Location.X + xPixelValue;
        var viewPointWidth = Math.Round((areaRightX - seriesLeftX - (series.Points.Count * 2)) / series.Points.Count, 0);

        return Convert.ToInt32(viewPointWidth);
    }
```

And this as well:

```
        private double GetChartAreaRightPositionX(Chart chart, ChartArea area)
    {
        var xLoc = chart.Location.X;
        return xLoc + (area.Position.Width + area.Position.X) / 100 * chart.Size.Width;
    }
```

The reason I'm calculating this is because I need to draw some graphical overlays on top of the normal chart item objects (my own rendering for my own purposes).

In the 'prepaint' event for the chart, I need to calculate the 'PixelPointWidth' that matches the current chart view (might be panned/zoomed).  I then use that value to SET the chart custom property to match . . . such that the normal chart entities and MINE are correctly aligned/scaled (ensures we're in exactly the right 'x' axis position):

In my prepaint event, I do the following - just prior to drawing my graphical entities:

```
                // Pretty close scwag . . .
                var viewPointWidth = CalculateChartPixelPointWidth(e.Chart, e.Chart.ChartAreas[0], e.Chart.Series[0]);

                // Set the custom property and use the same point width for my own entities .  .
                chart1.Series[0].SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth", viewPointWidth.ToString("D"));
                // . . .  now draw my entities below . . .
```